# Не загружаются шрифты в SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Изучая библиотеку SFML возникла проблема с подключением шрифтов.

Вроде, всё сделал верно: поместил файл необходимого шрифта в директорию с исполнимым файлом и ресурсами, указал путь (пробовал указывать как просто по имени файла, так и абсолютный путь из разных директорий и дисков), но всё равно возникает ошибка и шрифт просто не загружается. Соответственно, вместо ожидаемого текста выводится маленькая точка.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() 
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "test");
    sf::Font font;

        if (!font.loadFromFile("B:\\CS\\C++\\test\\arial.ttf"))
            std::cerr << "Error font" << std::endl;

        sf::Text text("Hello world!", font);

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                switch (event.type)
                {
                case (sf::Event::Closed):
                    window.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }


            window.clear(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
            window.draw(text);
            window.display();
        }
}
```

В итоге, всегда срабатывает условный оператор и выводит сообщение об ошибке "Error font". Что это такое может быть?

Comment: Без текста ошибки невозможно понять, в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ошибки компиляции или какой другой нет. Под "ошибкой" я подразумевал срабатывание условного оператора при невозможности загрузки файла по указанному пути, то есть это уже я сам ловлю и вывожу "ошибку".
Пробовал писать самые разные пути к файлу и использовать не только arial.ttf, но всё равно не получалось решить данную проблему

Comment: Проблема с файлом или путём к файлу. Проверил вашу программу на DejaVuSansMono.ttf - всё работает

Comment: @cpp questions, но что это может быть? Я испробовал все известные мне методы указания пути чтения из файла, проверял файл и использовал другие, но именно на моей машине ничего не получается :[
Есть предположение, что может быть проблема в том, что ОС каким-то образом не даёт доступ, но это вряд-ли, потому что с доступом к файлам через fstream нет никаких проблем

Comment: @Steindvart в остальном библиотека работает? Тестовый пример кружок рисует?

Comment: @Steindvart судя по [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21131393/10743113) и [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36315448/10743113) вопросам, вы могли смешать Debug/Release версии

Comment: @cpp questions, да, рисует. Может быть именно с загрузкой из файла что-то не так. Попробую сейчас загрузить какое-нибудь изображение в текстуру, чтобы проверить

Comment: @cpp questions, да, проблема с загрузкой из файла в целом. И да, я смешал Debug/Release версии. Сейчас с этим разобрался и всё понял. Спасибо большое за помощь! 
Впредь буду к этому внимательней относиться, ибо впервые сталкиваюсь с подобной проблемой и не особо придавал этому значения